# Automapper unable to save changes to destination table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Iam new to MVC. I am using Code first way.I am inserting data at UI which is linked ViewModel to multiple table like Customer class,Address Class,etc.My viewmodel properties are not same in all the reflecting table, For eg.

```
public class CustDetVM 
{   combined properties of all entity object }
 public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string A_Line1 { get; set; }
}
 public class User    
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string U_Group { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding data from my viewmodel to model. I am using three table to add data from viewmodel.

```
var query={// code removed for ..
   code is debugged properly and storing in query
    parameter.}



foreach(var data in query) //used debugger(breakpoint) here 
   {
     db.Customer.Persist().InsertOrUpdate(data);//used debugger(breakpoint) here 
   }
   db.SaveChanges();///used debugger(breakpoint) here not comming to this point and no error it is showing .
```

My mapping config is below

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
     {
       cfg.CreateMap<CustDetVM, Customer>()
        .ReverseMap();
      cfg.CreateMap<CustDetVM, Address>()
        .ReverseMap();                  
      });
```

What I am missing any help will be great for me.

Comment: Where are you calling `customer = Mapper.Map<Customer>(viewModel);`? Also, how to you map the `Customer.ID` and `Address.ID` from `CustDetVM`? These entities might not have the same ID in the DB (depending on how you configured the foreign key relationship).  `Persist()` and `InsertOrUpdate()` do not seem to be standard EF methods?

Comment: var customer = _mapper.Map<customer >(data); tried inside foreach loop above ,Id is guid so not appearing in my viewmodel say I make call by customer ID and enter new data on it,Yes Persist() and InsertOrUpdate() are extension of automapper.collection I am trying any way to insert data from the query.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkPrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<MyContext>>();` in the automapper config? But I still believe that the ViewModel must contain the correct DB ID so the backend can decide whether to insert or update. So you might need to map these IDs by hand. `cfg.CreateMap<CustDetVM, Customer>().ForMember(ent => ent.ID, o => o.MapFrom(vm => vm.CustomerID));` etc.